# Bulk Rename Utility: Rename Audio Track

Tags: javascript, substr, bulk-rename-utility

So I want to renme multiple audio tracks

***FROM***

*10. Black Hole Sun_Soundgarden*

***TO***

*10. Soundgarden_Black Hole Sun*

---

I found this:

```
var char2find = "_";
var index = name.lastIndexOf(char2find);
newName = name.substr(index+1) + char2find + name.substr(0,index);
```

But that moves the band name in front of the number like this:

*Soundgarden_10. Black Hole Sun*

All the files that I need to batch rename are in this same format: ***track#. Song_Artist***

I have tried to tweak it to fit my needs but have come up short. Can some let me know what I am doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the split method to split the Name and sequence number

> ```
> const name = "10. Black Hole Sun_Soundgarden"
> const char2find = "_";
> const [i, n] = name.split(". ")
> const index = n.lastIndexOf(char2find);
> const newName = n.substr(index + 1) + char2find + n.substr(0, index);
>
> const result = i + ". " + newName
> console.log(result) // 10. Soundgarden_Black Hole Sun
> ```

Comment: This is not for bulk renaming correct? I need it to rename 100's of different file names at the same time through the "Bulk Rename Utility" Wiindows app.

Comment: If the format is the same, it works for all

Comment: I get this error - Javascript Error: SyntaxError: Unexpedted token [in : const [i,n] = name.split(".") [Line.3 Start:6 End:7]

Comment: which node version do you use?

Comment: This is using the javascript renaming funtion in the windows App "Bulk Rename Utility". I hit ctrl+F7 paste the code in the window, click test and it throws the error. I don't know what node they might be using.